# C# windows forms How to play audio on webbrowser controller?

Tags: c#, winforms, html5-canvas, webbrowser-control

I prefer to use wavesurfer.js player in my web browser controller in C#.

The problem is wavesurfer isn't loading file.

Sample player is http://mypublic.kissr.com/

I am on windows forms applicaton. I tried with default webbrowser controller it didn't work.

then I tried with CefSharp browser controller. It still didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Data View Waves Timer and Pointer location all these are important to me. that's why I need to use wavesurfer.

Answer (score 0):

The link below, gives a very good tutorial, about playing mp3 files from a windows form with c#:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/292695/playing-mp3-in-c

This link will lead you to a topic, which contains a lot information about how to play an mp3 song, using Windows forms. It also contains a lot of other projects, trying to achieve the same thing:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3dbfb9a3-4e14-41d1-afbb-1790420706fe

For example use this code for .mp3:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

wplayer.URL = "My MP3 file.mp3";
wplayer.Controls.Play();
```

Then only put the `wplayer.Controls.Play();` in the Button_Click event.

For example use this code for .wav:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

player.SoundLocation = "Sound.wav";
player.Play();
```

Put the `player.Play();` in the Button_Click event, and it will work.

Comment: I want to implement like this http://mypublic.kissr.com/   waveform moving vertical like and seeking with mouse. hope you understand.